# how to change lookup reference between sharepoint lists?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, sharepoint-list, spfieldlookupvalue

I have simple Sharepoint list named Alist with lookup value column.

the lookup value column returns fields from other list named Blist. accidentally I have deleted this Blist and in Alist all lookup value disappeared, after I created new Clist identical to Blist.

now I am interested in how to change lookup reference from Alist to Clist?

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

You cannot change the lookup settings from Blist to Clist for the existing column.

In your Case you need to create new lookup column with reference to Clist.

**Note**: Creating new lookup column will loss all existing data of lookup from Alist.

Comment: but I want to restore lookup data in Alist

Comment: Do you have any backup from Alist? Any saved list template?

Comment: I have Alist with disappeared lookup column, and deleted Blist's identical Clist.